# What is the difference between vue.js method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently learning vue.js and see people building their methods differently. I'm curious what is the difference between these two:

One:

```
greet: function (event) {
   alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
}
```

Two:

```
greet(event) {
   alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
}
```

Comment: the 1st syntax belongs to ES5 specifications and the 2nd one which is new it belongs to ES6

Comment: it has nothing to do with vue, it is all javascript and the second is just easier and more recent way to define a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of the greet function accomplish the same thing.

The first version is more explicit as a key:value pair of an object, where `greet` is the object's key, with the function being that key's value.

Second version is shorthand (as mentioned in the comments, introduced in ES6).

They are both ways of writing **functions as expressions**.

**Function declarations** are similar to writing function expressions, you may be familiar with how they look

```
function greet(){
    alert('Hello')
}
```

They start with the `function` keyword before the name `greet`. They behave similarly to function expressions.

Where you write expressions in your page of code matters, as they do not load until interpreter reaches the line containing the expression.

Function declarations are hoisted to the top of their context.

More examples and details can be found:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function